# CPU-greedy loop when streaming music

Tags: c#, performance, audio-streaming

To give some context, I'm working on an opensource alternative desktop Spotify client, with accessibility at it's core. You'll also see some NAudio in here.

I'm noticing pretty intense CPU usage as soon as playback starts. Even when paused, the CPU is high.

I ran Visual Studio's inbuilt profiler to try and shed some light on any resource hogs that might be occuring. As I suspected, the problem wasin my playback manager's streaming loop.

The code that the profiler flags as one of the most sample-rich is as follows:

```
const int secondsToBuffer = 3;

    private void GetStreaming(object state)
    {
        this.fullyDownloaded = false;
        // secondsToBuffer is an integer to represent how many seconds we should buffer up at once to prevent choppy playback on slow connections

        try
        {
            do
            {
                if (bufferedWaveProvider == null)
                {
                    this.bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(44100, 2));
                    this.bufferedWaveProvider.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20); // allow us to get well ahead of ourselves
                    Logger.WriteDebug("Creating buffered wave provider");
                    this.gatekeeper.MinimumSampleSize = bufferedWaveProvider.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * secondsToBuffer;
                }
                // this bit in particular seems to be the hot point
                if (bufferedWaveProvider != null && bufferedWaveProvider.BufferLength - bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedBytes < bufferedWaveProvider.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond / 4)
                {
                    Logger.WriteDebug("Buffer getting full, taking a break");
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
                // do we have at least double the buffered sample's size in free space, just in case
                else if (bufferedWaveProvider.BufferLength - bufferedWaveProvider.BufferedBytes > bufferedWaveProvider.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * (secondsToBuffer * 2))
                {
                    var sample = gatekeeper.Read();
                    if (sample != null)
                    {
                        bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(sample, 0, sample.Length);
                    }
                }
            } while (playbackState != StreamingPlaybackState.Stopped);
            Logger.WriteDebug("Playback stopped");
        }
        finally
        {
            // no post-processing work here, right?
        }
    }
```

An NAudio sample was the inspiration for my way of handling streaming in this method. To find the full file's source code, you can view it here: http://blindspot.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Blindspot.Playback/PlaybackManager.cs

I'm a newbie to profiling and I'm not a year on year expert on streaming either (both might be obvious).

Is there any way I can make this loop less resource intensive. Would increasing the sleep amount in the if block where the buffer is full help? Or am I barking up the wrong tree here. It seems like it would, but I'd have thought half a second would be sufficient.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Take a profiler and run the profiler. VIsual Studio has one. Learn to use it.

Comment: "I ran Visual Studio's inbuilt profiler to try and shed some light on any resource hogs that might be occuring."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you've created an infinite loop until the buffer gets full. The section you've marked with

```
// this bit in particular seems to be the hot point
```

probably appears to be as the calculations in the if statement are just being repeated over and over again; can any of them be moved outside of the loop?

I'd put a Thread.Sleep(50) before the while statement to prevent thrashing and see if that makes a difference (I suspect it will).

Comment: I wasn't able to move the calculations out of the loop, as they needed to be reflective of the buffer's state at the time. A sleep made a world of difference though. Thank you! I gave it a 250 ms sleep at the end of the loop and after some faffing with VS (which didn't use the latest version of the playback assembly until I built it on its own through the context menu), CPU usage has plummeted